# Handle different activation log events in lifecycle methods

Tags: android, facebook, analytics

If you refer to any documentation about logging events (Facebook,GoogleAnalytics etc), or may be other different sdk things,  you can see activation helper methods that take place in lifecycle of concrete activity.

Ex:

[image]

The best way, I guess, to put such methods in BaseActivity. But sometimes it's not possible coz of project issues, where I can't use BaseActivity.
Is there any another way to handle all these things together in one place, (like interfaces or something)?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use BaseActivity? It's the obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you put it in each activity is because you want to know how much time a user is spending on each screen and track it. In your case if you want to simplify things add it in the application